# HLSL: problematic pixelshader code (alpha at zero when sampling)?

Tags: c#, directx, hlsl, pixel-shader

I have this strange problem with the sampler in the pixel shaders. When I sample from a sampler into an empty float4 variable I always get black/transparent color back. So if I use this I get a black screen:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
    {
        float2 uv = TextureCoordinate;          
        float4 pixelColor = tex2D(implicitInputSampler, uv);

        //contrast
        pixelColor.rgb = ((pixelColor.rgb - 0.5f) * max(Contrast, 0)) + 0.5f;

        //brightness
        pixelColor.rgb = pixelColor.rgb + (Brightness - 1);

        // return final pixel color
        return pixelColor;
    }
```

I I use this instead it works ok:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
    {
        float2 uv = TextureCoordinate;          
        float4 pixelColor = {0,0,0,1};
        pixelColor += tex2D(implicitInputSampler, uv);

        //contrast
        pixelColor.rgb = ((pixelColor.rgb - 0.5f) * max(Contrast, 0)) + 0.5f;

        //brightness
        pixelColor.rgb = pixelColor.rgb + (Brightness - 1);

        // return final pixel color
        return pixelColor;
    }
```

This happens only on my dev environment at home on a AMD 4850 GPU. When I try it on some nVidias or AMD5850 it works in any case...

What is the reason for this?
Did I miss some device initialization?

Cheers!

Comment: In the first case you are reading the output alpha from the texture and returning it.
Does your texture contain alpha values?

Comment: the texture is declared as A8R8G8B8, and i'm using stretchrectangle from the surface that VMR9 sends to the image compositor. It could be that the A in the VMR is alway 0 ? It's strange that this comes different with different graphic cards and  OSes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the A in the pixel shader source texture indeed is 0...

The texture is declared as A8R8G8B8 and device.StretchRectangle is used to fill the texture.

This method works differently depending on hardware :/

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know if the texture is 32 bit.  Mainly because I have come up against issues of AMD vs Nvidia.  In fact, what would be a non functional shader in one case was fully functional in another (AMD worked, NVIDIA didnt) just because I had an offset in my vertex buffer declaration off by 1 byte...but I digress, my question that each driver might be taking liberties on the interpretation of the alpha component if it is undeclared or not a true 32 bit texture.  Does the same thing occur if you use a different texture?   Is your alpha channel set to opaque (1.0f)?

Interested seeing I have had the old AMD/NVIDIA Driver behaviour differences before.  What works in one can actually be a error in the other driver.